# Problemas com required no select em angularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Pessoal possuo o seguinte código:

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-12 " style="    margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <label style="padding-top: 4px;margin-bottom: 3px;">Grupo</label>
    <select class="form-control " ng-options="grupo as grupo.descricao for grupo in vm.produto.listaGrupo" ng-model="vm.grupoSelecionado" required>
        <option value="">Escolha uma opção</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-12 " style="    margin-bottom:5px;">
    <label style="padding-top: 4px;margin-bottom: 3px;">Tipo</label>
    <select class="form-control " ng-options="subGrupo.codigoTabItemSubGrupoId as subGrupo.descricao for subGrupo in vm.grupoSelecionado.tabItemSubGrupo" ng-model="vm.subGrupoSelecionado" required>
        <option value="">Escolha uma opção</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

O meu problema é que os dois campos estão como required, mas ao dar submit com eles vazios, a operação acontece normalmente, mas o certo seria barrar a operação pois eles estão vazios. Todos os campos com required estão com o comportamento esperado, apenas esses 2 que são select que não estão fazendo a validação corretamente, se alguém conseguir me ajudar eu agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-required` para verificar se o valor do model está vazio ou não.
No caso: `ng-required="vm.grupoSelecionado"` e
`ng-required="vm.subGrupoSelecionado"`, vale lembrar que o ng-required é baseado em expressões.